# __filename throwing a reference error when using Rollup's typescript plugin in an AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, typescript, lambda, rollup

I've been battling this for a while now. I have an AWS Lambda which is running the rollup bundler in an AWS Lambda function, and uses the `typescript` plugin but it throws a an error:

`ReferenceError: __filename is not defined in ES module scope`

which is being thrown from the typescript module itself:

`at isFileSystemCaseSensitive (/.../node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:6361:41)`

I've tried all sorts of different configurations to make this work, but I continue to get this error. I feel like at this point I must have a fundamental misunderstanding about something. My current compiler options are:

```
 "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "ES6"
  }
```

but I've tried seemingly every other module and target under then sun.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you ever solve it?

Comment: @JulioMenendez unfortunately I did not. I ended up going down another path

Comment: Thanks, I ended up fixing it by adding this to the built files:
`import { fileURLToPath } from 'url'; const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);`

Comment: Yeah I found that solution but in my case it was part of a third party library so I couldn't directly modify the file. But glad you found a solution.